# verifyJWT not working in Ethr-did nodejs?

Tags: jwt, claims-based-identity

I am trying to generate and register a DID using  [ethr-did library.](https://github.com/uport-project/ethr-did/blob/develop/docs/guides/index.md)

I have created a did by

```
 const ethrDid = new EthrDID({provider, address, registry})
```

and then signed the payload by

```
const helloJWT = await ethrDid.signJWT({hello: 'world'})
```

but when i do this to verify by jwt

```
const {payload, issuer} = ethrDid.verifyJWT(jwt)
```

it gives an error that

```
(node:3310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported DID method: 'ethr'
```

I searched all over the internet but didnt found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to register the resolver first like this

registerResolver({provider : provider,registry:registry})